# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnotify in java.library.path

Tags: java, jnotify

I have configure Jnotify on Mac OS X. i am using MyEclipse and latest version of Jnotify. I am new to MAC OS and just added jnotify.jar and also added jnotify.dylib as a native library Its workling in development enviornment but when i create an executeable jar and run it on Mac OS X it will not work and the following exception has occured

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnotify in java.library.path
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert the following debug line in your code: `System.getProperty("java.library.path");`
If possible as the first line of your *Main* method.

Then run the executable jar and look at the path it prints. Now make sure that jnotify.dylib is located in one of the directories that the path displays.